# Power BI workspace - Unable to manage my dataflow assets

Tags: azure, rest, powerbi

Can someone explain how to go about **updating** a **dataflow** in Power BI using their REST API?  Is that accomplished via one of these:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/dataflows
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/imports

We keep our Power BI assets in source control (git repos).  When development work is complete we deploy to multiple workspaces (more than three).  This happens by way of REST API.

While the Power BI REST API's are sufficient to deploy our **datasets**, the available API's for deploying **dataflows** seem pretty inadequate.  For example, we are not able to update an **existing** dataflow that is already configured and is actively used (.. it has a gateway, data source connection, refresh schedule, and so on).

This type of automated deployment is just as necessary for our **dataflows** as it is for our datasets.

I've found blogs about managing my dataflows, like this one...
https://data-marc.com/2019/10/22/move-dataflows-across-workspaces-with-the-power-bi-rest-api/

... and I've even found Microsoft examples like this one...

https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-powershell/tree/master/examples/dataflows
(it uploads changes to dataflows via the **nameConflict=Overwrite** argument in DFUtils.psm1)

However in practice whenever I try to update my dataflows by REST API, I encounter lots of inexplicable error messages (like "**DuplicatePackageNotFoundError**").  Of course none of these types of REST error messages are especially useful or actionable.  I'm assuming the API is just buggy.  Before I start working with Microsoft tech support, I'm hoping someone can tell me what level of quality I should expect out of a Power BI REST API, and whether it is reasonable to manage my dataflows in the same way as my datasets.

Comment: Here are blogs about maintaining dataflows by REST API.  It is clear that there is a demand for this functionality (so long as it works).

https://ssbipolar.com/2019/10/03/importing-model-json-to-create-a-new-dataflow/
https://data-marc.com/2020/12/02/update-move-dataflows-across-workspaces/
https://data-marc.com/2019/10/22/move-dataflows-across-workspaces-with-the-power-bi-rest-api/

Comment: Earlier in the month I found this statement in the Microsoft docs: "Dataflows can be overwritten with the CreateOrOverwrite parameter, if they have initially been created using the import API" ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/dataflows/dataflows-features-limitations#api-considerations

Comment: As-of today(2023-02-20) Microsoft is claiming that some of the API functionality (overwriting an existing dataflow) is transitioning from supported to "unsupported".  However there are still plenty of blogs and Microsoft-provided examples that demonstrate how to use the "unsupported" features of this REST API.

Comment: Microsoft support acknowledged that this was a bug in the past (before it became "unsupported").  Their KB/Bug ID is  875909.  The title of the KB/Bug is : REST API - imports with parameter CreateOrOverwrite throws PackagenotfoundError ... and the bug was created back in Sept 2022.

Comment: I'm in the process of creating a CICD solution for PowerBI and we have had to leverage the DFUtils module and the ImportModel from same repo to try and upload the model.json file. It is definitely cumbersome, and is not supported with a service principal so you must use a user account in the pipeline, but we have had some success. If you think I can help I can write a more comprehensive answer on how we approach each task via API

Comment: Microsoft keeps hinting to me that they are working on a "V2" of their power BI API's.  I don't want to sound negative but I'm not holding my breath.  I just wish they would throw meaningful/actionable errors in *english*, rather than "DuplicatePackageNotFoundError" (whatever that means).  I think the folks who built the API's are not native-english-speaking people.  I think they work out of Israel and their English is passable, but still quite confusing.

Comment: We are in the same boat, we are just trying to find a now solution to get over a hump but either we are using PowerBI as it was never intended to be used, or the API support is poor currently. We are essentially extending the DFUtils module and calling it from Azure Pipelines with a mix of SPN and User Login depending on the API we need to call, it is incomplete at the minute but if we can finalise something I might be able to share some of it if it helps.

Comment: I have a ticket that has been open for months related to DuplicatePackageNotFoundError.  There are some obscure underlying reasons why the REST api will fall over.  Oddly they are now claiming the API is only supported if the dataflow was "originally" created via REST.  I have also found other scenarios that generate meaningless error messages.  I think one of the errors has to do with publishing a dataflow (even as admin) if the data sources had been previously configured by a different admin.  Truly weird.  Seems like a single-user platform. ;)

Comment: The good news is that Microsoft did a 180, and they now claim they've transitioned from unsupported back to supported (again).  The support for REST is predicated on whether the dataflow was "originally" created via REST.  I'm not that convinced by the lip-service.  Saying it is supported is one thing, and actually supporting it is another.